# GGplot2: plotting values per year of specific columns in a dataframe

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am trying to plot values on the y axis against years on the x axis with ggplot2.

This is the dataset: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1nJYtXPrxD0xvq6rBz2NXlm4Epi52rceM/view?usp=sharing

I want to plot the values of specific countries.

It won't work by just specifying year as the x axis and a country's values on the y axis. I'm reading I need to melt the data frame, so I did that, but it's now in a format that doesn't seem convenient to get the job done.

I'm assuming I haven't correctly melted, but I have a hard time finding what I need to specifically do.

What I did beforehand is manually transpose the data and make the years a column, as well as all the countries.

This is the dataset transposed:

https://drive.google.com/file/d/131wNlubMqVEG9tID7qp-Wr8TLli9KO2Q/view?usp=sharing

Here's how I melted:

```
inv_melt.data <- melt(investments_t.data, id.vars="Year")

ggplot() +
  geom_line(aes(x=Year, y=value), data = inv_melt.data)
```

The plot shows the aggregated values of all countries per year, but I want them per country in such a manner that I can also select to plot certain countries only.

How do I utilize melt in such a manner? Could someone walk me through this?

Comment: What kind of plot do you want? See for instance [a recent answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56824221/how-to-plot-different-y-with-the-same-x-in-ggplot/56824979#56824979) of mine. There are many, many similar others in SO.

Comment: @RuiBarradas I think I came across this answer of yours as well. I tried to get the data in long form, according to exactly what you suggest. I would like a line plot with years on the x axis and values per country on the y axis, so I can add several lines of specific countries.

Comment: In that answer, use `geom_line`, not `geom_point` and remove both `geom_smooth` and `facet_grid`. It becomes just 2 code lines after `melt`.

Comment: @RuiBarradas I edited the question and added how I tried to plot, and the data after manually transposing. I hope it helps.

Comment: For line plots, how can both the `y` and `x` axes be catorgical (i.e., years, country). How does the numeric metric of interest display?

Comment: @Parfait Values

Comment: Sorry guys, I shared the same data set twice, just noticed. The 2nd link is edited.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are no columns named `"Year"` in the linked to data set, there are columns per year. So it need to be melted by `"country"` and then the `"variable"` edited with `sub`.

```
inv_melt.data <- reshape2::melt(investments_t.data, id.vars="country")
inv_melt.data$variable <- as.integer(sub("^X", "", inv_melt.data$variable))

ggplot(inv_melt.data, aes(variable, value, color = country)) +
  geom_line(show.legend = FALSE)
```

**Edit.**

The following code keeps only some countries, filtering out the ones with more missing values.

```
i <- sapply(investments_t.data[-1], function(x) sum(is.na(x)) == 0)
i <- c(1, which(i))
inv_melt.data <- reshape2::melt(investments_t.data[i], id.vars = "Year")

ggplot(inv_melt.data, aes(Year, value, color = variable)) +
  geom_line(show.legend = FALSE)
```

Comment: I'm sorry, I shared the same link twice. The transposed dataset which shows a column for years has a link now (2nd one).

Comment: Thank you for the help so far. I want to be able to plot selected countries, not all. I wasn't entirely clear on that.

Comment: @RoddyMacintyre See the edit.It has code implementing a possible selection criterion.

Comment: The edit isn't working as you described. I could subset before melting, maybe I'll stick with that. I do prefer not having to subset or anything of that kind, but rather have the data in a way to be able to select the countries entirely in ggplot.